# Changing variables dynamically in LESS with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, less

I had a "variables.less" file holding the list of all the variables for a particular layout. To change the layout view I need to rewrite the "variables.less" file or create new file like "variables1.less" and import it to my main style.less. I don't want to do in this way. I want to have only one file "variables.less".

I want to know whether the variables in the variables.less file can be defined with the javascript dynamically before the less file getting imported to the style.less where my entire styles are declared. Here I want to maintain all the variable values for different layouts in a JSON file and read it to the "variables.less" file accordingly.

Is it possible to solve the problem. If not possible can I have an explanation.

Thanks
in advance

Comment: So do you want to change the varable names dynamically ...??

Comment: I want to get the variable values dynamically. Not the variable names @Prasath K

Comment: I couldn't understand your question

Comment: I had a variable "@color: red", for other layout I wan to change it to "@color:green".  Now I am going to create one more variables.less file. but I want to get the color value from JSON object using javascript. I had this problem to create different look for the same layout

Comment: Just put a sample line and how you want to change it ...?? .. Be more brief to get answers

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
less.modifyVars({
    '@buttonFace': '#5B83AD',
    '@buttonText': '#D9EEF2'
});
```